How to use Android devices connected to a Mac for React Native development on a remote Windows VM?
I'm trying to set up a React Native development environment with the following setup:
Development machine: Remote Windows Virtual Machine on Google Cloud Platform
Device connection: Local MacBook Pro
Devices: Both wired (USB) and wireless Android devices connected to the MacBook
My goal is to:
Run all development processes (Metro server, building, etc.) on the Windows VM
Use the Android devices connected to my Mac for testing and debugging
Current approach:
Using SSH tunneling to connect the Mac and Windows VM:
ssh -N -R 5037:localhost:5037 -R PORT:<android_ip_address>:PORT -R 8081:0.0.0.0:8081 user@vm-ip-address
Attempted to forward ADB connections
The problem is not that it doesn't work, the port forwading responds well.
One  major problem is when I am installing the app, it always fails with an error "Unknown error" in Android Studio.
Adb devices command on the VM returns the localhost address, and that is also alright.
And I know this comes from adb because it is a brand new react-native app.
Questions:
How can I properly forward both wired and wireless ADB connections from the Mac to the VM?
Should ADB servers run on both machines, or just one? If one, which?
What's the correct SSH tunneling setup to achieve this?
I'm looking for a step-by-step guide on how to set this up correctly. Any help would be appreciated.
I have literally done all that adb reversing and all, the virtual machine sees the device, but it always fails on the install.
It's like it is confused on which adb server to install the app on since there are two adb servers running.
All necessary ports I can think of are open (8081 for metro, 5073 for adb, 22 for ssh)

As others have done what you are looking for: How to set up ADB for remote machine development and local device deployment I would isolate if it is a problem with Android Studio in the cloud VM by just using adb install command from the cloud to your local PC / Android device.

well i managed to get it working without his port forwader, but the problem comes when i am trying to install the app from android studio, or even with gradlew installDebug, as it just hangs on 97%.
i have read almost everywhere and it says the issue is most likely to do with the adb server its self. Any clue?
